# Called function does not change variable in main with same name

Tags: c++

I am having a confusion in expected and actual outcome. Please help me. The value should be 13 but it is coming to be 4 only.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int su(int x, int y)
{
    x = x + y;
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World\n";
    int x = 4, y = 9;
    su(x, y);
    cout << x;
}
```

Comment: Inside the `main`, you are not storing the return value of `su( x, y )` in `x`. Thus `x` keeps its value which is 4.

Comment: The parameter `x` inside `su` and the variable `x` inside `main`, which have the same name, are different variables nevertheless.

Comment: Your function is equivalent to `int su(int x, int y) { return x + y; }`. Assigning to a function's (non-reference) argument has no effect outside that function.

Answer (score 2):

The variables `x` and `y` in the function `su` are different variables than `x` and `y` in the function `main`. Therefore, the line

```
x = x + y;
```

will only affect the variable `x` in the function `su`, but not the variable `x` in the function `main`.

If you want to change the variable `x` in the function `main` too, then you must change the line

```
su(x, y);
```

to:

```
x = su(x, y);
```

If you want the variables `x` and `y` in the function `su` to not be different variables, so that changing them will also affect the corresponding variables of the function `main`, then you should instead make the function `su` take references to variables:

```
void su( int &x, int &y )
{
    x = x + y;
}
```

Now, changing the value of `x` and `y` in the function `su` will also change the variable `x` and `y` in the function `main`.

However, the first solution is probably better.